# Constraining Facebook Login Button

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, facebook-login

I am trying to constrain my facebook login button, but it's width is not matching those of my other buttons.

Here is my code to constrain the facebook login button

```
var facebookButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
```

This code is in the viewDidLayoutSubviews function

```
        // Constraints for button
for const in facebookButton.constraints{
        if const.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttribute.height && const.constant == 28{
            facebookButton.removeConstraint(const)
        }
    }

facebookButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
//facebookButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: googleSignUpButton.widthAnchor).isActive = true
facebookButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: 63)
facebookButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 64)
facebookButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
facebookButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: googleSignUpButton.topAnchor, constant: -15).isActive = true
```

This is the output, I want the width of the facebook button to match those of the other buttons.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do one of the following:

1: Set fixed widths for all buttons.

2: Set leading and trailing anchors to the Google buttons leading and trailing anchors.

3: Use a UIStackView

Answer (score 1):

Put this code inside `viewDidLoad`

```
view.addSubview(facebookButton)
facebookButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
facebookButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
facebookButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: googleSignUpButton.widthAnchor).isActive = true
facebookButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
facebookButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: googleSignUpButton.topAnchor, constant: -15).isActive = true
```